# How to change margin when using shadethm package?

Tags: margins, theorems

I'm using the `shadethm` package in order to have gray background for theorems. However, the outcome is not satisfactory because the margin is too narrow:

[image]

Can anyone show me how to change the margin of the `shadethm` package or show me another way to add shaded background to theorems while can specify margin?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I'd highly recommend having a look at the `mdframed` package- it has all kinds of settings that can be tweaked easily :)

Comment: @cmhughes, mdframed is quite good! Thank you for your recommendation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **cmhughes** has mentioned, the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package offers a lot more features and possibilities than `shadethm`, so I also suggest you to switch to `mdframed`. However, to answer your question, you can change the values for the lengths `\shadeboxsep` (controlling the distance between the start of color to start of text; in the four sides) and `\shadetextwidth` (width of the text body) , as in the following simple example in which I left `6pt` between the frame and the text, but keeping the total width equal to `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newshadetheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\setlength\shadeboxsep{6pt} 
\setlength\shadedtextwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\shadeboxsep\relax}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simple example with `mdframed`, showing some of its features; in particular, the ability to control individually (for each of the four sides) the separation between the frame and the text (this cannot be done easily with `shadethm`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  innerleftmargin=8pt,%
  innerrightmargin=8pt,%
  innertopmargin=12pt,%
  innerbottommargin=12pt,%
  backgroundcolor=gray!50,%
  skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
  skipabove=\baselineskip]{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of *shadethm*.  It has been superceded, long ago.  If you are starting a new project then you should use something else.  (This is an answer because I am unable to comment.)